# What GUID can I use as a placeholder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a database table that has a non null column of type `uniqueidentifier`. This was put in place for use in the near future. But for now, I need to use some placeholder. Can I simply use:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

for all the rows until a real guid is used when new rows are inserted in the future? Does SQL Server enforce uniqueness on this column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server will enforce uniqueness, **IF** and only if **you** put a unique constraint or unique index on that field. Otherwise, SQL Server will only enforce that the value must be NOT NULL.

Comment: very true, it's totally up to you

Answer (score 2):

As marc_s, says, you can do that because uniqueness is not enforced for uniqueidentifiers even in the same column of a table without an explicit declared unique index/constraint (after all, two rows can legitimately have the same foreign key).

**IF** this is just a temporary bootstrap, and in the future only real GUIDs (NOT NULL) are going to be allowed, I think this is an OK workaround to avoid generating GUIDs which just need to be replaced later and so not needing to keep a separate partially-initialized flag column or table of the temporary rows so you can fill in the appropriate GUIDs later.

**However**, from a design point of view, I'm more concerned about the semantics of what this special reserved GUID is, and why allowing a special reserved value is OK, but NULLs are not.  Like I said, if it's just temporary and in the steady state, you don't want to ever allow NULLs **OR** this special reserved 0, that's fine, but if you are going to continue to allow this special reserved GUID in steady state operations, I think that raises design questions.

Is it meant to be a foreign key?  If so, NULLs can be used (but a reserved key value like 0 which is not in the referenced table cannot).  If it's a loose association, storing the GUID in this table might not be a great design.

Comment: +1.  The very meaning of `NULL` is "unknown" or "undefined" - if the column can have unknown values then it should be nullable!  An empty uuid is no better than an empty string.

Comment: @Aaronaught, NULL interpretation is a can of worms indeed.  NOT NULL should be considered first in any column design, but usage of a NULL with a single interpretation should be preferred before single reserved values.  Then if multiple reserved values are needed (DateOfDeath: 1-not dead, 2-unknown date), then the design needs to think how to handle this reliably and ensure integrity and consistency and perimeter defense against both insertion and misinterpretation.

Comment: Cade, while I agree with you in general, in this case, it seems like NULL would be a viable choice over a "magic" / dummy value / placeholder, at least until the rest of the design comes about.

Comment: @Aaron - right - I question why the NOT NULL constraint on the table and unless that's a long-term design intention and this workaround is just temporary, I think it's fine, but if this behavior is intended long term, I would recommend using NULL.  If there are multiple special "No-GUID" cases, then either NULL with a flag/type column or some kind of associative link table is a better design.